# Multiple instances of the same ID populating in different columns because of the case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following results:

```
| Memb_i | p1 |  p2 |  p3 |
+--------+----+-----+-----+
|   2    | 0  |  1  |  0  |
|   2    | 1  |  0  |  0  |
```

when I run the below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ME1.MEMB_ID 
,CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P1' THEN 1 else 0 END AS P1_flag 
,CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P2' THEN 1 else 0 END AS P2_flag
,CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P3' THEN 1 else 0 END AS P3_flag
,CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P4' THEN 1 else 0 END AS P4_flag
FROM MEMBER_ELIGIBILITY ME1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLAIM CL
ON CL.MEMB_ID = ME1.MEMB_ID
```

what I'd like to see is the following

```
| Memb_i | p1 | p2 | p3 |
+--------+----+----+----+
|   2    | 1  | 1  |  0 |
```

notice how member 2 has all the fields it has values in in a single row opposed to having them in multiple rows.

Comment: apologies for the example. The idea is that memb_i, p1,p2,p3 are all field names and the 2|0|1| are the values I see. in this case the two lines that are separated by the ----+

Comment: @rohitvats that's correct. I just ran VBoka's and it does just that, single row per member. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you need but here is one way to get it:

```
SELECT ME1.MEMB_ID 
,MAX(CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P1' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS P1_flag 
,MAX(CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P2' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS P2_flag
,MAX(CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P3' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS P3_flag
,MAX(CASE WHEN CL.CLAIM_ID > = 1 AND cl.PROC_CD = 'P4' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS P4_flag
FROM MEMBER_ELIGIBILITY ME1
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLAIM CL
ON CL.MEMB_ID = ME1.MEMB_ID
GROUP BY ME1.MEMB_ID
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bee452bd6bcb54b6063335728719dc52)

Comment: I agree, I will remove it, the focus was to the MAX and group by I believe so people did not noticed. And... done... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7909fcc48ab6d8a2d13799f8b6be4e86)**

```
select 
m.memb_id,
case when c.P1_total > 0 then 1 else 0 end P1_Flag,
case when c.P2_total > 0 then 1 else 0 end P2_Flag,
case when c.P3_total > 0 then 1 else 0 end P3_Flag
from member_eligibility m
left join (
  select 
  memb_id, 
  sum(case when proc_cd = 'P1' then 1 else 0 end) 'P1_total', 
  sum(case when proc_cd = 'P2' then 1 else 0 end) 'P2_total',
  sum(case when proc_cd = 'P3' then 1 else 0 end) 'P3_total'
  from claim
  group by memb_id
) c on c.memb_id = m.memb_id
```